# Validate backbone Model WIth Nested Object

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I have on model and have some fields in that and one oject that has some more fields,and i am validate that using backbone validatation,validation working fine for name and age but for field in object(address) validation is not working.

How to validate field in address?

Ex.

```
var PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
name: null,//String
age: null,//Integer
address: {
   pincode : null,
   streetName : ''
}
}
validation: {
name: {
required: true
},
age: {
range: [1, 80]
},
address : {
  pincode :{
    required : true
  }
}
}
});
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Backbone.Validation documentation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) it says that :

***"Validating complex objects is also supported. To configure validation rules for objects, use dot notation in the name of the attribute, e.g 'address.street'."***

Hence in your case, for the validation of properties in address object it should be :

```
"address.pincode" : {
    required : true
}
```